# \dot{} behaves incorrectly, it prints an underscore instead of a dot above the symbol. What could be the issue?

Tags: errors

Using `\dot{}` produces this strange behavior: It prints an underscore at the bottom of the letter instead of dot above the symbol. I tried `\ddot`, the dot is printed in the middle of the letter, and only `\dddot` prints 3 dots above. I am really at a loss of what might be the problem. Any insights?

Comment: something in your document is changing the default behaviour. But only you know what is in your document.

Comment: It would really help if you posted a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that successfully replicates the issue you wish to fix.